# Visualising why divergence of vorticity is 0

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm new to fluid mechanics and preparing myself for university next year and I'm reading up on vorticity and circulation at the moment.

I understand the maths behind why the divergence of vorticity is 0, however, I cannot visualise why. I find it quite easy to visualise the divergence of magnetic fields, and that there is no net flow of magnetic field across a closed surface.

On another thread, an answer explains that the magnetic field lines always come back in a loop and therefore there is no divergence.

Could anyone shed some light on this and possibly help me understand this a little bit more, please?

Thanks :)